# @QueryParam or HttpServletRequest in java

Tags: java, rest

I have resource class - UserResource interface and I have defined an endpoint as getUsers.

Now I want to filter these users based on users status - (Active, Inactive) and its not mandatory so if I does not pass the status it will fetch all the users.

Now the question is should I pass this as **@QueryParam** or get it from

```sh
HttpServletRequest - httpServletRequest.getParameter("Status").
```

Which one from the above two is best way and in what scenario I should use which one.

**1.** First way is pass the status as query param and define in the resource file itself. Here UserResource is the controller interface or resource class. In getUsers method has **@QueryParam**.

```java
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    @Path(/user)
    public interface UserResource{

          @GET
          @Path("/")
          @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
          Response getUsers(@QueryParam("status") String status);

    }

    @Component
    Public class UsersResourceImpl implement UserResource{

    public Response getPlan(String status){

    String userStatus = status;
    // some logic

    } 
}
```

**2.** Second way is get the query param from HttpServletRequest. so I have 
autowired the HttpServletRequest and getting the query param from the 
httpservletrequest.

```java
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path(/user)
public interface UserResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    Response getUsers();

    }

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Component
Public class UsersResourceImpl implements UserResource{

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    public Response getPlan(String status){

    String status = httpRequest.getParameter(status)
        // some logic
    } 
}
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I honestly don't see any appealing reason to avoid using the [`@QueryParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) annotation given that you need the value from a query parameter.

Some benefits of using [`@QueryParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) that I can think of:

- The [`@QueryParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) annotation will automatically bind the value(s) of a query parameter to a resource method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean property. So you won't need to extract and parse parameters manually, once you respect some rules described in the [documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html):

  > The type `T` of the annotated parameter, field or property must either:
  >
  > 1. Be a primitive type
  > 2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument
  > 3. Have a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single 
  >      `String` argument (see, for example, [`Integer.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html?is-external=true#valueOf-java.lang.String-))
  > 4. Have a registered implementation of [`ParamConverterProvider`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ParamConverterProvider.html) JAX-RS extension SPI that returns a [`ParamConverter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ParamConverter.html) instance capable of a "from string" conversion for the type.
  >      Be `List<T>`, `Set<T>` or `SortedSet<T>`, where T satisfies 2, 3 or 4 above. The resulting collection is read-only.
- [`@QueryParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) can be combined with [`@DefaultValue`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) to define a default value for the parameter in case it's not present in the request.
- If multiple endpoints support the same query parameters, you could aggregate them in a class and receive an instance of such class as a [`@BeanParameter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html).

Comment: @GopalSinghania So please considering upvoting and accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Go with **annotations** (i.e @QueryParam) that's why we chose such framework , remember **convention over configuration**.